# Rational map $f: \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1$ defined on a cofinite set is everywhere defined

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following: Any rational map $f: \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1$ which is defined on a cofinite set of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2$ (and thus open for the Zariski topology being $T_1$) must be also defined on the whole $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2$ (and thus, is a regular function).

The result isn't true for rational maps $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1 \to \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1$. The rational map given by $(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1\setminus\{0\},\frac{1}{x})$ cannot be defined in any open Zariski neighborhood of $0$. Neither is true if the cofiniteness hypothesis of some set of definition of $f$ is abandoned. Both hypothesis, $f$ having two variables and the cofiniteness one, must be exploited.

Two results come to my mind which I think could come handy for this problem, but I'm not sure how exactly. They are the following:

1. Any non-constant polynomial of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with $k$ an algebraically closed field and $n\geq 2$  has an infinite number of roots
   (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355227/394668).
2. The identity theorem from the complex variable theory: any two holomorphic functions defined on a common open connected subset $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ and that coincide on a subset $S\subset D$ which has an accumulation point on $D$ must be the same function.

I cannot think of any potential proof which uses the hypothesis of the two variables of $f$. I have no clue on how this could be used.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A rational function $\Bbb A^2\to \Bbb A^1$ can be represented by an element $f$ of the function field of $\Bbb A^2$. The condition that $f$ is defined everywhere except for a finite set means that $f \in k[x,y]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for all height one primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset k[x,y]$. As $R=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \text{ of ht 1}} R_\mathfrak{p}$ for $R$ a noetherian normal domain, this implies that $f\in k[x,y]$ or that $f$ is actually regular on $\Bbb A^2$.

The result about the intersection of localization of height one primes can be found in Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*, Theorem 38, or as "Algebraic Hartog's Lemma" (11.3.11) in [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).

---

If you're looking for a more elementary proof, one option in this case is to write our representative of the rational map as an element $g/h$ for $g,h\in \Bbb C[x,y]$ and $h$ nonzero. As $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD, we may assume that $g,h$ are coprime. If $h$ is nonconstant, then every point on $V(h)$, a curve in $\Bbb A^2_\Bbb C$ and thus an infinite set gives that $g/h$ is undefined. But we assumed that $g/h$ was undefined in finitely many places, so $h$ must be constant after all and our map is regular.

Comment: @Ulam More generally, if $X$ is a normal variety over $k$ and $U\subset X$ is a dense open with $codim(X\setminus U)\geq 2$, then a morphism $U\to \mathbb{A}^1$ extends (uniquely) to a morphism $X\to \mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: Why does the condition "$f$ is defined everywhere except for a finite set" is equivalent to "$f\in k[x,y]_\mathfrak{p}$ for all height one primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset k[x,y]$"?
Also, I've seen on my edition of Matsumura that the result you say is actually Theorem 11.5. The book has no Theorem 38.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake - I meant to refer to Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra* and somehow swapped the reference. For the other question, suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is a height-one prime. In our case, that determines a curve, $V(\mathfrak{p})$, which has infinitely many points. Pick one of them where $f$ is defined: that means that $f\in k[x,y]_m$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal corresponding to our point. As $k[x,y]_m\subset k[x,y]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in the field of fractions, we have the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I do feel comfortable with everything except for the result "$R=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \text{ of ht 1}} R_\mathfrak{p}$ for $R$ a noetherian normal domain". I've just looked up the definition for a normal domain (which I understand but didn't see before) but I'm not keen with what Matsumura uses on the proof for this fact, I simply can't understand it. I don't know enough commutative algebra yet. Wouldn't there be a more elementary approach for this problem, perhaps? Maybe for the specific case of $k=\mathbb{C}$, instead of giving a general proof for arbitrary $k$.

Comment: @Ulam It might help to try to prove the equality $R=\cap_{p} R_p$ where $p$ runs over all primes of height one when $R$ is a field or a principal ideal domain.

Comment: @Ulam I've added another explanation which is a bit more elementary.